# Running couchbase cluster with multiple nodes in docker on windows 10

Tags: docker, couchbase

I created a `couchbase 4.0` docker container with single node on `windows 10`. And added node ip in host machine loopback and forwarded port in vitural box so that couchbase client in my app running in host can connect with node in cluster. I was able to connect and do db operation when I have single node in cluster.

However when I created multiple node cluster in docker on windows 10. I was not able to do db operation. In golang app running in host I got message `unable to complete action after 6 attemps` on get and set operation.

How to run couchbase cluster of multiple nodes in docker on same host in windows machine so that I can connect with cluster and do db operation from app running in host machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is not running inside of Docker host, as far as I know, you can't do this (I would LOVE to be proven wrong by a Docker expert).

Couchbase clients need access to every node in the cluster, and with Docker you can only forward one image to a given port outside the host. (FYI, there is a tool called sdk-doctor which you can use to verify connectivity/networking issues called [SDK Doctor](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/sdk-doctor)).

I would suggest running your golang app inside of the Docker host (using docker-compose is the way this is typically done).

Also, I would *highly* suggest upgrading to a more recent version of Couchbase.

Comment: With Couchbase 6.5 and later you can use the [`setting-alternate-address`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/cli/cbcli/couchbase-cli-setting-alternate-address.html) command to configure the nodes running in docker to advertise mapped ports instead of the standard ports. This is the technique used by the latest Couchbase Testcontainers module. It's probably a pain to do manually... you'd need to start the docker containers and map all of the ports used by couchbase to unique ports on the host... then run the setting-alternate-address command in each docker container.